# Why do I need to assign QBuffer to a variable in order not to crash QImageReader?

Tags: python, reference, pyside, pyside6, qbuffer

That's such a weird bug, if it's even a bug.

This works:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QBuffer, QByteArray, QFile, QIODevice

from PySide6.QtGui import QImageReader


image_path = Path('/home/p10/testIAMAGAGADS.png')
file = QFile(image_path)
file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
blob = file.readAll()
buffer = QBuffer(blob)
image_reader = QImageReader(buffer)
```

This crashes PySide6:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtCore import QBuffer, QByteArray, QFile, QIODevice

from PySide6.QtGui import QImageReader


image_path = Path('/home/p10/testIAMAGAGADS.png')
file = QFile(image_path)
file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
blob = file.readAll()
image_reader = QImageReader(QBuffer(blob))
```

I would expect an object created in a specific scope (albeit passed as an argument) to stay alive at least till the end of that scope.
PS: The same thing happens when I read the image from a file to a bytes object and pass it to QBuffer without binding it to a variable beforehand.

Comment: There's no bug or weirdness. You're not keeping a reference to the QBuffer object, so it gets garbage-collected. This is no different than doing e.g. `len(dict(a=1))`: the dict will be deleted after len returns. The image reader takes a pointer to a QIODEvice. If it tries to read from that device (via the pointer) after it's been deleted, a fatal error will occur.

Comment: Ok, I would expect that when the image reader "takes a pointer" - it makes a reference, but since it's a C++ lib it apparently just takes the pointer. It would've been nice to have a proper error message for that though.
PS: I would mark your reply as an accepted answer if you posted it

Comment: @petko10 Qt already uses warnings when doing things that are discouraged or "wrong" on *its* side. But destroying an object that is being used creates a problem in memory access, and that is much worse.

Comment: @petko10 I have expanded my comment to make a more complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no bug or weirdness here. The second example does not keep a reference to the QBuffer object, so it gets garbage-collected (by Python). This is no different than doing e.g. `len(dict(a=1))`: the dict will be deleted immediately after `len` returns. The image reader takes a pointer to a QIODEvice. If it tries to read from that device (via the pointer) after it's been deleted, a fatal error will occur.

The Qt docs will usually explicitly state whether ownership passes to the receiver, and there's no indication that [QImageReader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#QImageReader-1) will do this. In fact, the docs include the following:

> **Note**: QImageReader assumes exclusive control over the file or device
> that is assigned. Any attempts to modify the assigned file or device
> during the lifetime of the QImageReader object will yield undefined
> results.

One way to fix the second example would be to make the QBuffer a child of the QFile (since they both inherit QObject):

```
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtCore import QBuffer, QByteArray, QFile, QIODevice
from PySide6.QtGui import QImageReader

image_path = Path('/home/p10/testIAMAGAGADS.png')
file = QFile(image_path)
file.open(QIODevice.OpenModeFlag.ReadOnly)
blob = file.readAll()
image_reader = QImageReader(QBuffer(blob, file))
image = image_reader.read()
print(image)
```

(NB: when the QFile is deleted, Qt will automatically delete all its children as well).